# keep the original order when using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this simple code, trying to plot the figure. My intention was to plot the x axis ordered as what I made, i.e. the same as order_num: from 1:10 and then 10+. However, ggplot changed my order. How could I keep the original order I put them in the data frame.

```
    data_order=data.frame(order_num=as.factor(c(rep(1:10),"10+")),
    ratio=c(0.18223,0.1561,0.14177,0.1163,0.09646,
    0.07518,0.05699,0.04,0.0345,0.02668,0.006725))

    ggplot(data_order,aes(x=order_num,y=ratio))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the data: *(Notice the removal of `as.factor`, we will be doing it in the next step. This is not mandatory!)*

```
data_order=data.frame(order_num=c(rep(1:10),"10+"),
                      ratio=c(0.18223,0.1561,0.14177,0.1163,0.09646,
                              0.07518,0.05699,0.04,0.0345,0.02668,0.006725))
```

You need to work with the dataframe instead of the ggplot.

```
data_order$order_num <- factor(data_order$order_num, levels = data_order$order_num)
```

Once you change the levels, it will be as expected.

```
ggplot(data_order,aes(x=order_num,y=ratio))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: this indeed changed the order of the x label. But the ratio didn't change accordingly. As you can see from my original figure, when x=2, it should be the second highest.

Comment: Based on your comment, I found a solution:x_order_tot=factor(c(rep(1:10),"10+"),levels = factor(c(rep(1:11)))) data_order=data.frame(order_num=x_order_tot,                       ratio=c(0.18223,0.1561,0.14177,0.1163,0.09646,0.07518,0.05699,0.04,0.0345,0.02668,0.006725))

Comment: Glad that it helped you in arriving at the solution. @yangyang Please check the updated solution now.